# Can't Install node-sass with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: angular, npm, node-sass

I'm having an issue installing `node-sass` on my project. ít's installed globally, but for some reason my Angular project says it can't find the module.

When trying to install it as a dev dependency I get an error, I notice a particular line that says:

`npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017 Found installation at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community`

Is the only solution installing VS2017?

Full logs can be found below.

I've tried running with `--unsafe-perms` param and it didn't work either.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Daniel\Source\Repos\AFP_BackOffice\AFP.BackOffice.Web\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Daniel\Source\Repos\AFP_BackOffice\AFP.BackOffice.Web\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Source\\Repos\\AFP_BackOffice\\AFP.BackOffice.Web\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@14.17.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "C:\Python27\python.exe" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Python27\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version `C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import sys; print "2.7.16
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 14.17.0
npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '14.17.0' ]
npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "14.17.0"
npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 14.17.0
npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 14.17.0
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: C:\Users\Daniel\Source\Repos\AFP_BackOffice\AFP.BackOffice.Web\node_modules\node-sass\build
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? C:\Users\Daniel\Source\Repos\AFP_BackOffice\AFP.BackOffice.Web\node_modules\node-sass\build
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017 Found installation at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Found Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.19041
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Found Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Found Microsoft.VisualStudio.VC.MSBuild.Base
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Using this installation with Windows 10 SDK
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017 using installation: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: C:\Users\Daniel\Source\Repos\AFP_BackOffice\AFP.BackOffice.Web\node_modules\node-sass\build\config.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: C:\Users\Daniel\Source\Repos\AFP_BackOffice\AFP.BackOffice.Web\node_modules\node-sass\config.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: C:\Users\Daniel\Source\Repos\AFP_BackOffice\AFP.BackOffice.Web\node_modules\node-sass\common.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "msvs"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Python27\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Source\\Repos\\AFP_BackOffice\\AFP.BackOffice.Web\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-G',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=2015',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Source\\Repos\\AFP_BackOffice\\AFP.BackOffice.Web\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Source\\Repos\\AFP_BackOffice\\AFP.BackOffice.Web\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Daniel\\.node-gyp\\14.17.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\Daniel\\.node-gyp\\14.17.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Source\\Repos\\AFP_BackOffice\\AFP.BackOffice.Web\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\Users\\Daniel\\.node-gyp\\14.17.0\\<(target_arch)\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Source\\Repos\\AFP_BackOffice\\AFP.BackOffice.Web\\node_modules\\node-sass',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Source\\Repos\\AFP_BackOffice\\AFP.BackOffice.Web\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp verb command build []
npm ERR! gyp verb build type Release
npm ERR! gyp verb architecture x64
npm ERR! gyp verb node dev dir C:\Users\Daniel\.node-gyp\14.17.0
npm ERR! gyp verb found first Solution file build/binding.sln
npm ERR! gyp verb using MSBuild: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp ERR! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe ENOENT
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:269:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:467:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Source\\Repos\\AFP_BackOffice\\AFP.BackOffice.Web\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Daniel\Source\Repos\AFP_BackOffice\AFP.BackOffice.Web\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v14.17.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! This is a bug in `node-gyp`.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! Try to update node-gyp and file an Issue if it does not help:
npm ERR! gyp ERR!     <https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues>
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 7
```

Comment: That line is just saying it found Visual Studio there. It doesn't care that it's VS2019 or VS2017. The problem comes much farther down, where it runs MSBuild with the displayed argument. It even says ```This is a bug in `node-gyp`.```  It then suggests updating node-gyp and filing an issue if it doesn't help. Have you done any of that? You could also try running the MSBuild command yourself to see what the full error is. You'll need to figure out where that `build/binding.sln` is located, put MSBuild in your path, then run the command with the args as shown.

Comment: It looks like node-sass would need to update the version of node-gyp it depends on

Comment: I've updated node-gyp to the latest version, also tried version 7.1 which was recommended in a thread about a similar issue and neither worked.

Answer (score 3):

According to node-sass github page, supported node.js version vary release by release.

[enter link description here](https://github.com/sass/node-sass)

try:

```
sudo npm install --save-dev  --unsafe-perm node-sass
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact samme error. It seems as if it is an issue with Visual Studio 2019.

I removed Visual Studio 2019 and installed Visual Studio 2017 instead.

After that, I had no problem installing node-sass.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).